# Extract Section number from word document

Tags: powershell

Word document has this section:11.2 SQL Server Version Available

I have to search for this in word document

11.2 is section number and SQL Server Version Available is header

```
$SearchKeyword1 = '11.2 SQL Server Version Available'

'Get-Content $SourceFile | select-string -pattern $SearchKeyword1
```

how do we mention this search keyword using regex... so that it checks it has 11.2 and sql server version available in line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your `$SearchKeyword1` already checks that because it is a very specific string to look for. However, if you suspect other text to be in between the version number `11.2` and the text `SQL Server Version Available`, you could use something like this:

```
$SearchKeyword1 = '(?:11\.2).*(?:SQL Server Version Available)'
```

That of course searches for the literal version of `11.2`. If the version number can also be let's say `10.7`, you could do a more generic search like

```
$SearchKeyword1 = '(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:SQL Server Version Available)'
```

If you would like to check for ANY version in the text, you could do

```
$SearchKeyword1 = '(?<major>\d+)\.(?<minor>\d+).*(?:SQL Server Version Available)'
```

and from that figure out the version used from the `$matches['major']` and `$matches['minor']` values.

Hope that helps.

*By the way, since you are so interested in Regular Expressions (seeing this is not your first question about it), try reading some tutorials. I found an excellent free downloadable one here [Regular Expressions: The Complete Tutorial](https://www.princeton.edu/~mlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf)*